# Can I use my own HTML files with OpenCart?

Tags: opencart

I just want to implement the Shopping cart side of things where they add products to basket and quantities etc.

Would I have to select a theme or can I just add the things I want from it for my site?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have your own html files but make sure, all variables from controller are passing onto your view files...